# vim-go deleting unused code when write to disk

Tags: vim, go

I have imported several packages into a file in a Go package (`package commands`) I am writing (following along with a golang tutorial) using Vim with the Vim-Go plugin.  Several of these packages are not yet used in the package. When I save the file `:w`, Vim seems to be deleting the unused packages, which is really annoying because those unused packages are going to be used. I just haven't added the necessary code for them. Is there a way to turn off this functionality in Vim-Go or do I have to delete the whole plugin to get rid of this annoying behavior?

Before Write

```
package commands
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"

    rss "github.com/jteeuwen/go-pkg-rss"
    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)
```

After Save

```
import (
    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you're using `goimports` as the tool to use when formatting your go code (I think vim-go does this by default - and it formats code on save by default). `goimports` removes unused imports for you .. thats why its so great. You will learn to love it at some point :)

For now, what you want to use is `gofmt` to format your code, which doesn't touch imports - it only formats the code. You can put this in your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:go_fmt_command = "gofmt"
```

If you decide you want to manually run `goimports` on your file after you've done the above .. you can run `:GoImports`.

You can also choose another option if you prefer: you can turn off formatting on save by putting this into your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:go_fmt_autosave = 0
```

Then, you can still use `goimports` when formatting your code .. but it won't do it automatically on save.

Comment: Thanks, that's very odd default behavior imo as it discourages frequent saving of the file unless you force yourself into the odd behavior of only importing the package after the code is used, which is absolutely silly in go, as you can give packages custom names that you need to use in the code (see, for example, the `rss`) in the OP

Comment: Its not that odd - `goimports` works both ways. If you fire up a new file and type `http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)` - it will automatically import `net/http` for you. if you remove that line, it will remove the import. This saves incredible amounts of jumping around your file and keystrokes since unused imports are a compiler error. If you decide you want to use `net/http` you have to jump to your imports .. manually import it.. jump back .. etc. `goimports` saves all of that.

Comment: ok, I hadn't stumbled on that yet. All the same, I prefer not to use it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem at all. Happy Gophering :)

Comment: In fairness, it does state that on the vim-go github README... so its right there on the front page. "Braindead hamster" is incredibly harsh when its in the readme. That said, the Go team heavily encourage people to run their code through `gofmt` .. so its not too outrageous to have it enabled by default in a plugin.